# Migrate link from mobile web browser to mobile app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, deep-linking

I want that my online website link that is opened in my mobile browser checks whether my mobile app is installed or not and then opens it in my mobile app.

I want my functionality as I have shown in this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMBKt.jpg)

I am using AngularJS,Express,NodeJS in my application.I tried [node deeplink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deeplink)
but it does not work for me.Please provide me with the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is known as Mobile Deep Linking. The easiest way to get started is with a deep linking service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), [Yozio](http://www.yozio.com), or [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/). They all do exactly what you're describing.

Comment: Is mobile browser capable enough to detect mobile app and open it?

Comment: Mobile browsers can open an app if it is installed. However that is an OS-level function, and you (as the website owner) do not receive any information or callback. All you can do is attempt to launch the app using a supported method and then handle _both _ possible results.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/). It has guides and plenty of examples that should get you going!

Answer (score 0):

this could Help you perhaps:
[Check this](https://developers.tune.com/sdk/deep-linking-to-your-mobile-app-from-your-website/#_ga=1.171380960.1514850860.1475217881)